# How to set number of reducer dynamically based on my mapper output size?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, distributed

I know that the number of mapper can be set based on my dfs split size by setting mapred.min.split.size to dfs.block.size.

Similary how can set I the number of reducers based on my mapper output size?

PS: I know that the below options can be used to manipulate the number of reducer.
mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum
mapred.reduce.tasks

Answer (score 2):

No of reducers can not set after job submission. 
Think about it this way - partitioner is called on the mapper output and it needs to know no of reducers to partition.

Answer (score 1):

To set number of reducer task dynamically:

The number of maps is usually driven by the number of DFS blocks in the input files. Although that causes people to adjust their DFS block size to adjust the number of maps.

So in the code below, let us set the number of reducer tasks dynamically to adjust with the number of map tasks at runtime.

In Java code:

```java
long defaultBlockSize = 0;
int NumOfReduce = 10; // you can set anything
long inputFileLength = 0;
try {
    FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(this.getConf()); // hdfs file
                                                            // system
    inputFileLength = fileSystem.getContentSummary(
            new Path(PROP_HDFS_INPUT_LOCATION)).getLength();// input
                                                            // file or
                                                            // files
                                                            // stored in
                                                            // hdfs

    defaultBlockSize = fileSystem.getDefaultBlockSize(new Path(
            hdfsFilePath.concat("PROP_HDFS_INPUT_LOCATION")));// getting
                                                                // default
                                                                // block
                                                                // size
    if (inputFileLength > 0 && defaultBlockSize > 0) {
        NumOfReduce = (int) (((inputFileLength / defaultBlockSize) + 1) * 2);// calculating
                                                                                // no.
                                                                                // of
                                                                                // blocks
    }
    System.out.println("NumOfReduce : " + NumOfReduce);
} catch (Exception e) {
    LOGGER.error(" Exception{} ", e);
}

job.setNumReduceTasks(NumOfReduce);
```

Comment: it is not an answer for the question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the number of mappers and reducers through command line dynamically::
you can use the below options:

**-D mapred.map.tasks=5 -D mapred.reduce.tasks=5**

We can also set the number of mappers and reducers in the driver code:
 job.setNumMapTasks();
 job.setNumReduceTasks();

I dont think you can dynamically change the number of reducers once the map reduce job started.As far as i know,there would be no human interaction of providing values during the job is being run.It should be preconfigured. Map Reduce job is a batch process(runs long time),so it hard for user to know when it would ask the user for number of reducers and it is not designed to be interactive during this process!! Hope you got the answer !!

Comment: @Merla: Thanks for the response. But still the suggestions does not provide an optiont to change them dynamically during the job run in case of difference in volume when processing the data.

Comment: I dont think you can dynamically change the number of reducers once the map reduce job started.As far as i know,there would be no human interaction of providing values during the job is being run.It should be preconfigured. Map Reduce job is a batch process(runs long time),so it hard  for user to know when it would ask the user for number of reducers and it is not designed to be interactive during this process!! Hope you got the answer !!